# how does i know is loggedin user is selecting the checkbox ..?

Tags: sql, asp.net, checkbox, foreign-keys, userid

I had gone through so many answers related to this question but i am not getting what i want.

I am very new to both asp.net and Sql .
actually what i want to do is ,after the user got log in in to his account he has to select checkbox , then his user id and his selection should be stored in the table.

I am bit confused about how to do this
should i have to make user id of the second table as FK to the user id of the first table
I am novice to both asp.net and sql server. I hope some one will show me the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Really broad question. Can you give better examples? Are you trying to make something like a *contract agreement*?

Comment: i want user to select his mood..like smilies which are in check box.So my doubt is how can i know which user selected which smilie.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Is it Forms authentication? This is what is going to determine how you can retrieve the user id in the backend. I don't the reasons for you to store this data neither how you are going to use it, this might also influence on you database design. At first, I would say that you should create a table of UserMood, that, apart from the id, will have an integer identify the mood of the user, a FK for the user id, and maybe a datetime2 to indicate when the user had that mood. If you have an ever growing set of moods you cold also have a Mood table.

Comment: i want to use asp.net login control for login and forms authentication to redirect to another page

Comment: Can you please explain me with a small example..

Comment: So you're using webforms. If you are new, check the asp.net tutorials that might help you. [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/security/create-a-secure-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-user-registration-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) has an example of authentication with webforms, check how the data for the logged in user is retrieved in the `Login` method.

Comment: For example if i had a mood table , should i have to make the userid in that as FK and i can aslo use datetime and in another column the usermood will be present  and it should be integer not text..?

Comment: Yeah. It actually depends on your needs. If the mood is going to be a free text created by the user, you could have it stored as a text (`nvarchar` of you're using SQL Server). If you have a predefined limited set of moods, that is not likely to change, you could have an enum in your code. The value of this enum would be stored in an integer column.